# Will future Android devices still support OpenGL ES 1.x?

Tags: android, opengl-es, backwards-compatibility, opengl-es-2.0

Since OpenGL ES 2.0 is **not** backward-compatible to OpenGL ES 1.x because of it's [lack of pipeline functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_ES#OpenGL_ES_2.0), but current Android devices support both standards, I wonder if it will remain this way in future.

Any public statements known about that?

*Note: it's related to my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281923/android-gl-es-2-0-multi-colored-code-sample).*

Comment: Sorry, but this question can't be answered...

Comment: Quite unrelated comment: No matter if it will or not, it is not a bad idea to switch to 2.0 as soon as possible, as it can probably be guaranteed, that future devices will support this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no information about the end of maintenance of the OpenGL ES 1.1 API.

This, in the IT industry means that the product has several years of life in front of it.

Years, in the constantly evolving IT market is quite a lot of time :)

Anyway, according to Khronos, this is the roadmap:

To respond to your question, what I understand from this document is that OpenGL 1.1 will be kept for low end devices. At least for the time being.

[image: Khronos Roadmap]

Comment: I hope they won't stop supporting OpenGL ES 1.1 for at least a couple years from now on. Otherwise I would be in a big trouble :D OpenGL ES 2.0 is just an overkill for what I have to do and Canvas can not do what I want. Or at least I didn't find it in 3 hours. It's a pitty OpenGL becomes overcomplicated as it improves.